# Biblatex introduces an extra period if the title ends in uppercase letter

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I am doing a presentation using beamer and I am using the \fullcite command from biblatex to put some full citations on a slide. The problem that I have is that biblatex somehow introduces an additional point in the full citation before the name of the journal when the title of the respective article ends in an upper case letter as shown in the following image

[image]

How do I do about removing the extra point?

I have only experimented with the article class, I don't know if the same behaviour is exhibited for other classes as well.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% bibliography
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test_biblio.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% customize the presentation style 

% set the overall theme
\usetheme{default}
% set the color theme 
\usecolortheme{beaver}

% remove the navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% add the page counter to the footer(as the navigation is removed)
% also keep the formatting set by the theme
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
    {\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1ex]{author in head/foot}
      {\textit{\insertshorttitle}} \hfill {\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber }
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}[plain]

\title{A title}
\date{A date}
\author{An author}

\maketitle

\end{frame} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}

A full citation

\fullcite{cit_key}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

The content of the test_biblio.bib file is the following:

```
@article{cit_key,
    author          = "Another author",
    title           = "A title that ends in an upper-case letteR",
    journal         = "A journal",
    year            = "2018"
}

@article{cit_key2,
    author          = "Another author",
    title           = "A title that does not end in an upper-case letter",
    journal         = "A journal",
    year            = "2018"
}
```

Cheers,
Andrei

Comment: I don't get a second period with your example. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: I think that it might not be that up to date.  The biblatex version is 3.7 and the date is 2016-12-06 08:05:45 +0100.

The problem is that I really didn't have the time recently to update it and I'm hard pressed for the presentation and do not have the time to update it right now.

Comment: Try if it works if you add `\@` behind the uppercase letter: `letteR\@`.

Comment: Your proposed solution works. Could you please add it as an answer so I can vote it and close the question? And may I ask why does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This is not necessary in newer biblatex versions. The bug leading to the double period has been resolved).

You can add in the bibfile `\@` after the uppercase letter: `letteR\@`. Then biblatex will not see the uppercase letter.

Comment: Related to this beamer issue: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/331 I don't actually think it was a `biblatex` bug.